# Using moment.js, can my date or my date timezone change if I use a VPN?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm new with javascript and I am using moment.js.

My code is `const date = moment()`.

Let's supposed one of my website's user (A) is using a VPN, locating him to an area using a different timezone. The other user (B) is using the website in the same country but with no VPN.

Will the value of `date` be different for the two users, and will it's timezone be the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily, although it has nothing to do with the IP address/VPN usage.

The date, time and timezone that `new Date()` will give is entirely dependant on the host OS configuration. There's even no way you can guarantee that 2 machines on the same network have the same/different time or date.

Comment: I am not using new Date() but moment() though! Does that change something?

Comment: @Virthuss Nope, invoking `moment()` uses `moment.now()` to set the datetime that is used for that instance and `moment.now()` uses `new Date()`. [Documentation here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/)

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer.